# Adjacency list representation using vector of vectors(2D vector) in C++

Tags: c++, vector

We can fill adjacency list in BFS using 1D vector like `vector<int> adj[10];` we can fill that vector as follows:

```
main(){
    int x,y,nodes,edges;
    cin>>nodes>>edges;
    for(int i=0;i<edges;i++){
        cin>>x>>y;
        adj[x].push_back(y); //Insert y in adjacency list of x
    }
}
```

Now how can we use 2D vector(or vector of vectors) to fill the adjacency list instead of 1D vector for
2D vector be can be like `vector<vector<int> >g;`
So how can we populate that 2D vector for building adjacency list ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say, maximum value of x could be **n**.
First you have to initialize the 2D vector with **n** number of 1D vector.
Then you can perform the operations like you did in your example.

```
vector<vector<int> >g;
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    vector<int>v;
    g.push_back(v);
}

g[0].push_back(3);
g[1].push_back(5);
cout<<g[0][0]<<endl;
cout<<g[1][0]<<endl;
```

Or you can initialize the vector at the time of declaring.

```
vector<vector<int> >g(n);

g[0].push_back(3);
g[1].push_back(5);
cout<<g[0][0]<<endl;
cout<<g[1][0]<<endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

vector<vector> g(nodes, vector());

g[0].push_back(3);
g[1].push_back(5);

Comment: Pravin Mote, while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).