# Why adjacency list uses array of vectors and not vector of vectors in graphs in c++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph

So, I already know that adjacency list can be implemented using vector of vectors from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41530010/adjacency-list-representation-using-vector-of-vectors2d-vector-in-c)

Here is a implementation of adjacency list taken from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20in%20the%20below%20implementation%2C%20we%20use%20dynamic%20arrays%20(vector%20in%20C%2B%2B/ArrayList%20in%20Java)%20to%20represent%20adjacency%20lists%20instead%20of%20the%20linked%20list.%20The%20vector%20implementation%20has%20advantages%20of%20cache%20friendliness.%C2%A0%0A%C2%A0).

```
    // A simple representation of graph using STL
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// A utility function to add an edge in an
// undirected graph.
void addEdge(vector<int> adj[], int u, int v)
{
    adj[u].push_back(v);
    adj[v].push_back(u);
}

// A utility function to print the adjacency list
// representation of graph
void printGraph(vector<int> adj[], int V)
{
    for (int v = 0; v < V; ++v) {
        cout << "\n Adjacency list of vertex " << v
            << "\n head ";
        for (auto x : adj[v])
            cout << "-> " << x;
        printf("\n");
    }
}

// Driver code
int main()
{
    int V = 5;
    vector<int> adj[V];
    addEdge(adj, 0, 1);
    addEdge(adj, 0, 4);
    addEdge(adj, 1, 2);
    addEdge(adj, 1, 3);
    addEdge(adj, 1, 4);
    addEdge(adj, 2, 3);
    addEdge(adj, 3, 4);
    printGraph(adj, V);
    return 0;
}
```

But I still want to know why it is implemented using array of vectors everywhere and not vector of vectors when they can serve the same purpose.

Comment: What do you mean "everywhere"?

Comment: What is the difference between an array and a vector? Do you mean C-arrays? Please add some code examples into your question.

Comment: @NathanPierson By everywhere I mean , in all the tutorials and videos I saw for the implementation everybody is using an array of vectors.

Comment: @Evg Yes the arrays that were in C . I have added the code now and it is in C++ .

Comment: I mean, you obviously don't see it _everywhere_. You've linked to exactly one reference implementation of an adjacency list, and it uses a vector of vectors. I can't read the minds of unknown people who wrote unshown code.

Comment: Just a bad code example from a typical "coding" website. These websites spread bad examples and do tremendous harm to C++ community. They have nothing to do with professional programming.

Comment: @NathanPierson Sorry , but how do I put it . I have watched numerous tutorials and implementations . All I want to know why they specifically use array of vectors and not vector of vectors. What's the difference between the two  ?

Comment: The code you are showing is not proper standard C++ code. You can only use an automatic storage duration array of vectors instead of a vector of vectors if the number of vertices is fixed at compile-time, which it isn't really in the case you show since `V` is not `const` at all. In most situations you wouldn't know the number of vertices at compile-time, so array of vectors usually is not a useful implementation.

Comment: I was trying to learn graphs for coding interview from GeeksForGeeks( I have added the link in the post). So what is the answer to it ? What is the difference when using vector of vectors and an array of vectors ?

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` are already big indicators that the code in question is not of good quality. And the website you linked to is known for providing bad and sometimes even outright incorrect code examples

Comment: @heysujal `vector<int> adj[V];` -- Again, this code is not valid.   *I was trying to learn graphs for coding interview from GeeksForGeeks(* -- That website is notorious for bad code, bad examples, bad explanations.  It is too bad that so many new programmers go to that site to learn C++.  If you showed up at an interview using that `bits` header, or declaring arrays using runtime values as their size, you can bet that you won't be hired.

Comment: @heysujal -- [This shows the code you have does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/6jnnfE5ab), all due to what was pointed out with the array declaration.  Also, even if you used the correct standard header (not the `bits` header), the same error shows up at the line the array is declared.  So your example of using arrays isn't valid C++ code -- the code that is valid [is the one with vector](https://godbolt.org/z/xGjhqcqPE).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the code I mentiond works fine on my local machine.

Comment: @heysujal -- If you used the correct compile flags (`-Wall -pedantic`), your code will not compile, or will warn you that the syntax is not valid.  This is why I wished that `g++` (which you are probably using to compile with) would turn *off* the "extensions" by default, and instead, compile the code using ANSI C++ compliance.  By using that compiler without the proper compiler flags, you were fooled into thinking the code was valid, when it isn't valid.  Now that you know the code isn't valid C++, you now see that why `vector` was used.

Comment: @heysujal `void printGraph(vector<int> adj[], int V)` -- The vector should be passed by (const) reference, not by value.  Another reason why that GFG site is a bad website to learn C++ from.  If `g++` were used properly (strict ANSI C++ compile mode), most of the examples at that site would fail to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has some problems and I would not be surprised if it gets flagged or removed. First of all a “why” question may simply not have an answer, since reasons as to why something is what it is may be innumerable and include personal, historical or social aspects and sometimes even mere chance.

Moreover, your assumptions are biased and maybe simply wrong. Please note that tutorials and YouTube videos have a tendency to oversimplify things, an effect of their didactic goals.
Real world, production ready code is much more complex and nuanced in order to properly function in a myriad of different contexts and conditions.

Bringing the issue to your question’s subject, graphs implementation in c++, I suggest you take a peek at the boost graph library to get and idea of how a professional, proven implementation really looks like.
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html

Notice that the choice of the container type is left to the user; and the tests include linked lists of linked lists (std::list), vectors of vectors, and sets of vectors and sets of lists. In general, using plain C arrays in C++ is not the best choice, the STL containers provide more safety, efficiency and convenience.
https://github.com/boostorg/graph/blob/develop/test/adj_list_cc.cpp

I think some of the comments here are unnecessarily rude and do not help if you’re a beginner trying your first steps in the hard field of software programming. The fact that you posted this question show your interest and openness to learning. Keep studying and eventually you will understand what’s odd in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using an array of vectors for an adjacency list doesn't usually make sense.

If the array is automatic storage duration it needs to have a compile-time fixed size, which implies that the implementation works only with one particular number of vertices at runtime, which is typically not what you want.

If the array is created with `new`, then there is no benefit over just using `std::vector` instead. Both will use an array with dynamic storage duration anyway.

Exceptions might apply for example if you know at compile-time that you only need to consider small graphs below a certain number of vertices, but then you probably would consider using an alternative to an adjacency list with variable-length entries anyway. For example storing the adjacency matrix might be more cache friendly in such a situation, or an adjacency list with fixed contiguous memory allocations per entry.